# Code is being executed even after return statement is there?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am using mongoose unique validator to make name and email in my user model unique. And when i try to save a duplicate user in database it is giving me error which is ok , but even after returning the response, the code below the return statement is being executed and i am getting an error that says
" Error:  Can't set headers after they are sent."
Here is my code.

User.js:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");
var crypto = require("crypto");
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'cant be blank'],
            unique: true,
            match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
            index: true
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            unique: true,
            required: [true, 'cant be blank'],
            index: true
        },
        salt: String,
        password_hash: String
    }, { timestamps: true });

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, { message: "already taken" });

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password) {
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(15).toString('hex');
    //console.log(this.salt);
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512').toString('hex');

    //console.log(this.hash);
}
userSchema.methods.checkPassword = function (password) {
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 10000, 512, 'sha512').toString('hex');
    return this.hash == hash;
}

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

router.js

```
//route for Signup


router.get("/signup", function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup.html');
});
router.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var verify = req.body.verify;
    if (!name || !email || !password || !verify || password != verify) {
        var passwordError;
        if (password != verify)
            passwordError = 'Password are not matching';
        res.render('signup.html', { 'Error': 'Invalid Details', 'name': name, 'email': email, 'passwordError': passwordError });
        return;
    }

    var newUser = User(
        {
            name: name,
            email: email

        });
    newUser.setPassword(password);
    newUser.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            //console.log("Database Error:%s" , err);
            console.log(err);
            // Even after using return statement the code below this 
            // statement is being executed . I dont know why?
            return res.status(500).send({ success: false, message: 'User already exists' });
        }

    });
    console.log("here");

    req.session.user = newUser;
    console.log(newUser);
    res.redirect('/newpost');
});
```

Note : I have not added the full code for router.js file.
I know a workaround for this problem will be to add the remaining code in an else statement.But i am not getting why this error is coming at first.

The error i get in console is:

```
{ _id: 5a645473ae051e159a62f080,
  name: 'dipen',
  email: 'dipenbhatt12@gmail.com',
  salt: '2f3e989389918507aaea0915b59852' }
  { [ValidationError: User validation failed: name: already taken]
  errors: 
  { name: 
  { [ValidatorError: already taken]
    message: 'already taken',
    name: 'ValidatorError',
    properties: [Object],
    kind: 'unique',
    path: 'name',
    value: 'dipen',
    reason: undefined,
    '$isValidatorError': true } },
  _message: 'User validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError' }

events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:767:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
at /home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/router.js:141:27
at /home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3907:16
at /home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:334:16
at /home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:246:48
at next (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:167:27)
at Kareem.execPre.Kareem.execPost.callback [as execPost] (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:217:3)
at _handleWrapError (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:245:21)
at /home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:271:14
at _next (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:94:14)
at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/asmodeus/Programs/HelloWorld/node_modules/kareem/index.js:420:34)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Comment: Look closely at where that `return` is. It returns from the `save()` callback. It does not affect the function where that `save` is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So how should i return from that entire function once i get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the fact that `save` returns a Promise:

```
  //Make the route async
 router.post('/signup' , async function(req,res){

   //validate user input
   const { name, email, password, verify } = req.body;
   if(!name || !email || !password || !verify) 
      return res.json({ error:"Wrong data"});
   }

   //create a new user
   const user = User({ name, email });

   // asynchronously save it to db, catch all errors
   try {
     await user.save();
     //return valid response
     return res.json({success: true});
   } catch(e){
     return res.json({error:"dupe"});
  }
});
```

---

Your code does not work because you simply cant return from a callback. That returns to the internal function that called the callback.

Comment: Isn't the  callback for the route a async by default.And i am not clear on that await,does the use of await here pauses the call back function for /signup until the save is done.

Comment: @dipen yes exactly. The await will waut until the user was saved and then continues executing the code. If saving fails and the promise gets rejected, await will throw and the code will enter the catch block.